# How to implement bi-directional maps

Tags: java, algorithm

I am aware that Google's guava and even Apache commons offer bi-directional maps. However, I would like to know how they are implemented. From the little I found, the most simplest way is to use 2 separate maps to store key/value and value/key data. However, surely there are better ways? Surely Google's implementation is not this straightforward? Where is the magic?

Thanks!

Comment: You can see Guava and/or Apache commons source code.

Comment: Both are open source projects. Why don't you browse their source code?

Comment: From what little I explored, Guava uses 2 maps e.g., the putInBothMaps method is used. but is that it? is there something else that is hidden away? im reaching out to anybody with more experience than me in using these datastructures.

Comment: Guava team member here: nope, that's it.  Well-written data structures are _supposed_ to be straightforward and obvious.  (Mind you, some work I'm doing might make it a bit more magical...)

Comment: @LouisWasserman hey i'd like to accept your answer.

Comment: @JBNizet Hi, can you help me out with where exactly to find the source code for the Apache or Guava implementation of Bidirectional Map. I've heard people talk of looking at the source code, but where do I get that from? Thanks.

Comment: @Kraken: For Guava, it's quite simple: you browse the javadoc, click on the links, and you'll eventually see the source code. Or you go to the home page of the project (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and click the *Source* tab. For apache commons collections, you go to the home page of the project (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) and click "Source repository" in the left-side bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently that's all it is (Louis Wasserman).

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, a type of bidirectional map could actually be implemented with a single Object->Object map, with the (key,value) pair inserted into the map twice, once for each direction. As long as you didn't require an explicit inverse view, it would work. In the case where the keys and values were of the same type (allowing the same object to be a key and a value), you could only have a single mapping between a given key and value (O1->O2 implying O2->O1), whereas with traditional BiMaps you could effectively have two (O1->O2 with inverse O2->O1 AND O3->O1 with inverse O1->O3). But for many bidirectional map needs, the single-map solution would suffice.

Comment: You could do it with a single map without restrictions, if you decorated each key with an indication of the direction of the mapping. So a `BidirectionalMap<String, String>` would be implemented with a `Map<Pair<String, Direction>, String>`, where `Pair` is a simple pair and `Direction` is a two-value enum.